# Evaluating an expression using snake oil

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I have to evaluate this expression: $\sum_k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}(-2)^{-k}$,

(In the original question we had $\sum_k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}(-2)^{k}$)

this is what I have done:

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_n\sum_k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}(-2)^{-k}x^n
& = \sum_k\sum_n\binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}(-2)^{-k}x^n \\
& = \sum_k\binom{2k}{k}(-2)^{-k}\sum_n\binom{n}{k}x^n \\
& = \sum_k\binom{2k}{k}(-2)^{-k}\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}} \\
& = \frac{1}{1-x}\sum_k\binom{2k}{k}(\frac{x}{2x-2})^k
\end{aligned}$$

now we know that $\sum_k\binom{2k}{k}x^k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$ and so we get

$$ \sum_n\sum_k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}(-2)^{-k}x^n
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$

So the sum that I'm looking for is equal to $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{-1/2}{k}(-1)^k\binom{-1/2}{n-k}$

there is a way to express this expression without using sums or menus signs?

Comment: There is a typo $(-2)^k \frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}} = \frac{(-2 x)^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$, not $\frac{1}{1-x} \left( \frac{-2x}{2x-2} \right)^k$.

Comment: @Sasha: I fixed it

Comment: Some people may not know what "Snake Oil" means. See section 4.3 of Wilf, generatingfunctionology: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

Comment: If this result is true:

$$\sum_n\left(\sum_k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}(-2)^{-k}\right)x^n
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Then you just want the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$.

So don't we get:

$$\sum_k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}(-2)^{-k}=\begin{cases}0&n\text{ odd}\\
\binom{-1/2}{n/2}&n\text{ even}
\end{cases}$$?

Answer (score 3):

**Added**: This post answers the **original** question, which is to compute $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k} \binom{2k}{k} (-2)^k$.

---

Assuming the typo is corrected you correctly arrived at the result:
$$
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x)(1+7 x)}}
$$
Where $c_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k} \binom{2k}{k} (-2)^k$. Using 
$$
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{n!} x^n
   \qquad
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+7x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{n!} (-7 x)^n
$$
Thus
$$
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x)(1+7x)}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \sum_{m=0}^n \frac{1}{\pi} (-7)^m \frac{\Gamma(m+1/2) \Gamma(n-m+1/2)}{m! (n-m)!} 
$$

The sum over $m$ is the closed form which can, alternatively, be represented as a hypergeometric polynomial, giving
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  c_n &=& \sum_{m=0}^n \frac{1}{\pi} (-7)^m \frac{\Gamma(m+1/2) \Gamma(n-m+1/2)}{m! (n-m)!} \\ &=&
    \frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) n!} {}_2 F_1\left( \frac{1}{2}, -n; \frac{1}{2}-n ; -7 \right) \\ &=&
 {}_2 F_1 \left( \frac{1}{2}, -n ; 1 ; 8 \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

---

**Added**: To address OP's skepticism that the above is the correct solution to the question posed, here is some numerical verification using *Mathematica*:

```
In[73]:= Table[{Sum[
   Binomial[n, k] Binomial[2 k, k] (-2)^k, {k, 0, n}], 
  Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -n, 1, 8], (
  Gamma[1/2 (1 + 2 n)] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -n, 1/2 - n, -7])/(
  Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1 + n])}, {n, 1, 6}]

Out[73]= {{-3, -3, -3}, {17, 17, 17}, {-99, -99, -99}, {609, 609, 
  609}, {-3843, -3843, -3843}, {24689, 24689, 24689}}
```

Comment: It should be simpler, we didn't study the gamma function and the meaning of the symbol $_2F_1$

Comment: @AlexM Have you checked that you copied the problem correctly?

Comment: Actually the professor told me that there is a typo in the exercise, I will edit the question

Comment: we should have $(-2)^{-k}$ instead of $(-2)^k$

Comment: @AlexM You should not have removed the previous edition of your question, but rather updated the question, so that readers of this post could relate what I wrote to your question. Please make sure that the original question is available.

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Hi I want to provided an expression without sums and negative signs and some python code to verify the validity of the answer. I'm still new to combinatorics so pls point out any mistakes!

I think your expression for the generating function of the term is correct. Let me label $Z(x)=\sum_n z_n x^n$ where $z_n=\sum_k \binom{n}{k} \binom{2k}{k} (-2)^{-k}$.

So we want the expression for $z_n$, which is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $Z(x)$. Since the second term in $(1-x^2)$ has a power of 2, so we want the $(\frac{n}{2})$-th term in the binomial expansion of $(1-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. And using the binomial formula, we see the $\frac{n}{2}$-th term is $\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{n}{2}}1^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2}}(-x^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}$, so the coefficient of $x^n$ is $$\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{n}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}$$. Note that $\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{n}{2}}=\frac{(-\frac{1}{2})_{(\frac{n}{2})}}{(\frac{n}{2})!}$ this term is only defined when $n$ is even because the argument to the factorial function has to be an non-negative integer by definition. So we can drop the $(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}$ term and when $n$ is odd, we should make it 0, which is also the coefficient of the terms where $x^n$ has odd exponent.

Now we expand $\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{n}{2}}$

$$
\begin{aligned}
    \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{n}{2}} &=
    \frac{(-\frac{1}{2})_{\frac{n}{2}}}{(\frac{n}{2})!}\\
    &=\frac{
    (-\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{1}{2}-1)(-\frac{1}{2}-2)...(-\frac{1}{2}-(\frac{n}{2}-1))
    }{
    \frac{n}{2}(\frac{n}{2}-1)(\frac{n}{2}-2)...1
    }\\
    &=\frac{
    (\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2}+1)(\frac{1}{2}+2)...(\frac{1}{2}+(\frac{n}{2}-1))
    }{
    \frac{n}{2}(\frac{n-2}{2})(\frac{n-4}{2})...\frac{2}{2}
    }\\
    &=\frac{
    (\frac{1}{2})(\frac{3}{2})(\frac{5}{2})...(\frac{n-1}{2})
    }{
    \frac{n}{2}(\frac{n-2}{2})(\frac{n-4}{2})...\frac{2}{2}
    }\\
    &= \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 ...(n-1)}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}   \frac{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}{2\cdot 4\cdot ...n}\\
    &= \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 ...(n-1)}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}   \frac{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}{2\cdot 4\cdot ...n}\\
    &=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 ...(n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot ...n}\\
    &=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 ...(n-1)(\frac{n}{2})!2^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(\frac{n}{2})!2^{\frac{n}{2}}(\frac{n}{2})!2^{\frac{n}{2}}}\\
    &=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 ...(n-1)2\cdot 4\cdot ...n}{(\frac{n}{2})!2^{\frac{n}{2}}(\frac{n}{2})!2^{\frac{n}{2}}}\\
    &=\frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{2})!(\frac{n}{2})!2^n}
\end{aligned}
$$

I also wrote some python code to do a sanity check on the first few terms of the sum and the answer, and turned out at least the first 20 terms are the same.

```
from math import comb
import math

'computes Zn'
def z(n):
    acc = 0
    for k in range (n+1):
        term = comb(n,k)*comb(2*k,k)*(-2)**(-k)
        acc += term

    return(acc)

'computes my answer -1/2 choose n/2 times (-1)^(n/2)'
def ans(n):
    if n%2==1:
        return 0
    numerator = 1
    for i in range(int(n/2)):
        numerator = -numerator*(-0.5-i)
    denominator = math.factorial(n/2)

    return numerator/denominator
```